# How to show multiple location tooltips together on button click in react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-ref

I know the same question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870405/q-react-native-maps-how-to-use-marker-showcallout-for-an-array-of-coordinate), but still I am not able to get that works

I have multiple coordinates for users location and I want to show all locations tooltip with username on the single button click

Also tried this : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1899#issuecomment-234485054

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455293/react-native-how-to-show-the-tooltip-with-out-clicking-on-marker-in-react-nativ) question too but it is working for one marker only while I need to show all the marker's tooltip together.

The answers on above questions are not full-filling my requirement, I have tried that everything with different ways but still need your help to complete the requirement.